# Position sticky isn't working even without any parent having overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

```js
// observer for feature section
let featuresSection = document.querySelector('#featuresSection');

let callbackFeature = (items) => {
    items.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.isIntersecting) {
            item.target.classList.add("in-page");

        } else {

            item.target.classList.remove("in-page");

        }
    });
}
let observerFeature = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFeature, {
    threshold: 0.3
});
observerFeature.observe(featuresSection);
```

```css
.features-section.in-page {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;

    position: sticky !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
  }
  
   .features-img {
   width:100%
    object-fit: contain;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
<div class="vh-100"><div>

<section id="featuresSection" class="features-section ">
        <h2 class="text-center">Newest set of Advanced Features</h2>
        <h3 class="text-center mb-5 clr-primary">Achieve the impossible</h3>

        <div class="row wrapper features-row h-100">
          <div class="col-6 px-0 col-md-4 order-md-2 features-img-container">
            <img id="ftr-img-1"
              class="features-img "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81LNgb-7FnL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-2"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/911Gc7IMlmL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-3"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91z5KuonXrL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-4"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81jYRL0oCSL._AC_SX679_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div
            class="col-6 pl-3 pr-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-1 pr-md-4 pl-md-0 features-col "
          >
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4>High Performance</h4>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit?
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4>Long Lasting Battery</h4>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit?
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="col-12 px-0 d-flex mt-3 mt-md-0 flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-3 pr-md-0 pl-md-4 features-col "
          >
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4 class="text-md-right">Titanium Case</h4>
              <p class="text-md-right">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4 class="text-md-right">New GPS Antenna</h4>
              <p class="text-md-right">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

*What could be the causes of a sticky element **not working** besides:*

- Having a parent element with any overflow:hidden
- Not having set the top position to stick to
- The sticky element being a flexbox or grid
- Sticky property not having browser support

Because my element doesn't have any of those problems, I even checked for an overflow:hidden in the css both with CTRL+F and with a script that checks for it in the console. Yet **it doesn't stick** to the top of the page.
Thanks in advance.

This is the **CSS** for my section:
Background red is for debugging and it works, but the sticky property doesn't work.

```
.features-section.in-page {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;

    position: sticky !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
  }
```

And this is my section itself:

```
<section id="featuresSection" class="features-section ">
        <h2 class="text-center">Newest set of Advanced Features</h2>
        <h3 class="text-center mb-5 clr-primary">Achieve the impossible</h3>

        <div class="row wrapper features-row h-100">
          <div class="col-6 px-0 col-md-4 order-md-2 features-img-container">
            <img id="ftr-img-1"
              class="features-img "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81LNgb-7FnL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-2"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/911Gc7IMlmL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-3"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91z5KuonXrL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-4"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81jYRL0oCSL._AC_SX679_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div
            class="col-6 pl-3 pr-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-1 pr-md-4 pl-md-0 features-col "
          >
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4>High Performance</h4>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit?
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4>Long Lasting Battery</h4>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit?
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="col-12 px-0 d-flex mt-3 mt-md-0 flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-3 pr-md-0 pl-md-4 features-col "
          >
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4 class="text-md-right">Titanium Case</h4>
              <p class="text-md-right">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4 class="text-md-right">New GPS Antenna</h4>
              <p class="text-md-right">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

And this is my JS that uses an Intersection observer to add the position sticky and also a background color red for debugging:

```
// observer for feature section
let featuresSection = document.querySelector('#featuresSection');

let callbackFeature = (items) => {
    items.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.isIntersecting) {
            item.target.classList.add("in-page");

        } else {

            item.target.classList.remove("in-page");

        }
    });
}
let observerFeature = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFeature, {
    threshold: 0.3
});
observerFeature.observe(featuresSection);
```

Comment: Well, the snippet doesn't work properly cause it needs more classes to look like my version apparentely, but I can assure you on my side the background is red when it gets the class in-page and it's not sticky

Comment: Your section is the only element in your snippet, there is nothing behind it, so it is sticky  to body/html but body/html  pushes it  up from the bottom. A sticky element will follow the position of its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky shall not fill its entire parent to be visually sticky.
once it reaches the bottom of its closest positionned parent, it will move with it and will not overflow. If another sticky element comes in the way, it also moves away.

Your example with some elements before and after let you see that it does stick:

```js
// observer for feature section
let featuresSection = document.querySelector('#featuresSection');

let callbackFeature = (items) => {
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.isIntersecting) {
      item.target.classList.add("in-page");

    } else {

      item.target.classList.remove("in-page");

    }
  });
}
let observerFeature = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFeature, {
  threshold: 0.2
});
observerFeature.observe(featuresSection);
```

```css
.features-section.in-page {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.features-img {
  width: 100% object-fit: contain;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="vh-100">
  <div>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <section id="featuresSection" class="features-section ">
      <h2 class="text-center">Newest set of Advanced Features</h2>
      <h3 class="text-center mb-5 clr-primary">Achieve the impossible</h3>

      <div class="row wrapper features-row h-100">
        <div class="col-6 px-0 col-md-4 order-md-2 features-img-container">
          <img id="ftr-img-1" class="features-img " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81LNgb-7FnL._AC_SX569_.jpg" alt="" />
          <img id="ftr-img-2" class="features-img d-none d-md-block " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/911Gc7IMlmL._AC_SX569_.jpg" alt="" />
          <img id="ftr-img-3" class="features-img d-none d-md-block " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91z5KuonXrL._AC_SX569_.jpg" alt="" />
          <img id="ftr-img-4" class="features-img d-none d-md-block " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81jYRL0oCSL._AC_SX679_.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 pl-3 pr-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-1 pr-md-4 pl-md-0 features-col ">
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4>High Performance</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit?
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4>Long Lasting Battery</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 px-0 d-flex mt-3 mt-md-0 flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-3 pr-md-0 pl-md-4 features-col ">
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4 class="text-md-right">Titanium Case</h4>
            <p class="text-md-right">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4 class="text-md-right">New GPS Antenna</h4>
            <p class="text-md-right">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
    <p>give it some space</p>
```

**But you probably only want the titles to stick**

Let's do this and see it working ;)

```js
// observer for feature section
let featuresSection = document.querySelector('#featuresSection');

let callbackFeature = (items) => {
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.isIntersecting) {
      item.target.classList.add("in-page");

    } else {

      item.target.classList.remove("in-page");

    }
  });
}
let observerFeature = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFeature, {
  threshold: 0.3
});
observerFeature.observe(featuresSection);
```

```css
.features-section.in-page {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.features-img {
  width: 100% object-fit: contain;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="vh-100">
  <div>
  <p>Would it be anything here before?</p>
    <section class="features-section">
      <hgroup id="featuresSection" class="features-section">
        <h2 class="text-center">Newest set of Advanced Features</h2>
        <h3 class="text-center mb-5 clr-primary">Achieve the impossible</h3>
      </hgroup>
      <div class="row wrapper features-row h-100">
        <div class="col-6 px-0 col-md-4 order-md-2 features-img-container">
          <img id="ftr-img-1" class="features-img " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81LNgb-7FnL._AC_SX569_.jpg" alt="" />
          <img id="ftr-img-2" class="features-img d-none d-md-block " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/911Gc7IMlmL._AC_SX569_.jpg" alt="" />
          <img id="ftr-img-3" class="features-img d-none d-md-block " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91z5KuonXrL._AC_SX569_.jpg" alt="" />
          <img id="ftr-img-4" class="features-img d-none d-md-block " src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81jYRL0oCSL._AC_SX679_.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 pl-3 pr-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-1 pr-md-4 pl-md-0 features-col ">
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4>High Performance</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit?
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4>Long Lasting Battery</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 px-0 d-flex mt-3 mt-md-0 flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-3 pr-md-0 pl-md-4 features-col ">
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4 class="text-md-right">Titanium Case</h4>
            <p class="text-md-right">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-info-container">
            <h4 class="text-md-right">New GPS Antenna</h4>
            <p class="text-md-right">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

**Notes** that prefix are no longer needed for nowdays browsers. !important is also not necessary, but z-index can be handy :).

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation! Actually I needed the whole section to be sticky, because I wanted to create a particular effect where the section stays still, with a single visible image in the center, and only the image changes on scroll until the images finish. So the actual problem of the full section not sticking was the z-index or am I still wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you wanted - but you don't need the intersection observer (though I applaud the use of these newer DOM methods).... If you are simply looking for the header elements to stick to the top pf the page on scrolling - then you need to apply the position-sticky to them - not the entire section.

For simplicity - I wrapped the h2 and 3 in a div - and put the position sticky onto that. Note that you also need the z-index to ensure that the content scrolls under the stuck header content.

I removed the intersection observer to demonstrate the new div and the style changes.

```css
.header-wrapper {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;

    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    z-index: 99
  }
  
   .features-img {
   width:100%
    object-fit: contain;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
<div class="vh-100"><div>

<section id="featuresSection" class="features-section ">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <h2 class="text-center">Newest set of Advanced Features</h2>
        <h3 class="text-center mb-5 clr-primary">Achieve the impossible</h3>
     </div>

        <div class="row wrapper features-row h-100">
          <div class="col-6 px-0 col-md-4 order-md-2 features-img-container">
            <img id="ftr-img-1"
              class="features-img "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81LNgb-7FnL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-2"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/911Gc7IMlmL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-3"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91z5KuonXrL._AC_SX569_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <img id="ftr-img-4"
              class="features-img d-none d-md-block "
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81jYRL0oCSL._AC_SX679_.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div
            class="col-6 pl-3 pr-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-1 pr-md-4 pl-md-0 features-col "
          >
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4>High Performance</h4>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit?
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4>Long Lasting Battery</h4>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit?
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="col-12 px-0 d-flex mt-3 mt-md-0 flex-column justify-content-between col-md-4 order-md-3 pr-md-0 pl-md-4 features-col "
          >
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4 class="text-md-right">Titanium Case</h4>
              <p class="text-md-right">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="features-info-container">
              <h4 class="text-md-right">New GPS Antenna</h4>
              <p class="text-md-right">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ducimus facilis aut totam amet veniam ab. Eius optio obcaecati
                laudantium suscipit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for you time, although I needed the full section to be sticky using the intersection observer, to be able to remove the sticky attriute later on (It's for a kinda complex effect that I wanted to give to the section); But the important thing is that apparentely without z-index it couldn't work, right?

Comment: hi - the z-index is needed to allow lower content to slide under the sticky content on scroll. it will still be sticky without the z-index - but you may find the other content scrolling over top of the fixated content.